# agetty login program arguments

Tags: centos, tty, serial-port, getty

First post here. I'm trying to run some tests against a CentOS 6 machine, but my tests disable networking so I communicate over serial ports.

I created an upstart job that sets up ttyS1 such that it has a bash root shell on it. I used:

```
/sbin/agetty -n -l /bin/bash ttyS1 115200 vt102
```

This is a hack, running /bin/bash as a login program. It works, but I would like to pass `--rcfile` to `/bin/bash` (otherwise, I get some undesirable output of "bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied", even though it is being run as root).

Note: the version of agetty being used has neither --version nor --login-options.

Answer (score 1):

`agetty` expects a program to run for the `-l` option.  You could make that (for instance) a Perl script, and make *that* provide the parameters, e.g., call this script `myshell`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
exec 'bash --rcfile myprofile'
```

and use the pathname of `myshell` in the `agetty` command.

I used **Perl** because it does not read your `bash` (or `sh`) profile.  If you use a script that runs `/bin/sh`, it can read the user's `.profile` (which seemed contrary to your intent).  The `exec` feature is provided in other scripting languages (including `sh` and `bash`).

Comment: I already attempted another script to no avail.

    `#!/bin/sh
    /bin/bash --rcfile /etc/bashrc`

I didn't try `exec /bin/bash ...` though.

Comment: I wonder if agetty can even run a script as a login program, or if it only allows binaries.

Comment: It doesn't matter: `agetty` is using an `exec` (C runtime) call which only asks the kernel to run whatever that pathname is.

Answer (score 0):

You may think it is overkill, but rather than using getty and running a shell on the serial line, you could try using [SLIP](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linux_Networking/SLIP_client), Serial Line Internet Protocol. This turns your serial port into a network interface over which you can connect multiple logins simultaneously using ssh or whatever, send files using rsync, and so on, all with the advantage of reliability and error detection.

It is simple to setup and use, assuming your kernel supports it (usually the case). The easiest way is with the `slattach` command, which is usually in the `net-tools` package. On one machine give the commands

```
sudo slattach -p cslip -s 19200 /dev/ttyS0 &
sudo ifconfig sl0 192.168.1.2 pointopoint 192.168.1.3
```

where the first command specifies the baud rate and serial device, and the second provides the IP address of that machine, and of the other machine.  On the other end give the same commands, swapping over the 2 IP addresses.  Choose a set of addresses that you are not already using.