# Networking over serial port

Tags: linux, networking, serial-port

I have an embedded board and it is having a web server running. Unfortunately, it has only a serial port (network port is not enabled). Is there a way where I can access the web server using s browser from a Linux PC(connected using a serial interface)?. I could see many ways to do the reverse(make serial available over the network) but not this one.

Thanks,
RL

Comment: you can use **slip**. See the details in my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322258/119298)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PPP (Point-to-point Protocol) to send and receive IP packets over the serial line. This requires setting up a PPP Daemon (`pppd`) on both ends. PPP over serial lines was used when connecting to the Internet using modems. You can find lots of tutorials on-line.